# How to read or write data from .plist file in Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, plist

1. Need to fetch data from plist file
2. Need to display the data in UITableView in Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems totally unclear to me. Would be better if you clarify it. Please read
FAQ, -> http://stackoverflow.com/tour How to Ask -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and help center -> http://stackoverflow.com/help as a start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly trivial to read from a plist.

Make sure the build action of the plist file is "Bundle resource".

Then you can read the contents of the plist, if it's a dictionary:

```
var dict = NSDictionary.FromFile (path);
```

Or it's an array:

```
NSArray array = NSArray.FromFile(path);
```

From the NSArray you can populate a UITableView.

I'd advise you check out the tutorial on Xamarin's website, for populating a UITableView, its very clear and concise.

[1] http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/

Edited to read from as a dictionary, per @jstedfast advice in the comment

Comment: Be careful with assuming that the plist is an array, they are generally dictionaries, so you'd want to use `var dict = NSDictionary.FromFile (path);` instead.

Comment: Updated my answer to include reading from a dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: It was the 'BundleResource' build setting that was the key for me. Thanks for this.